# When starting protractor --elementExplorer, the console gets stuck at "Debugger listening on port 5858"

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I've been picking up Protractor a little recently, and I was looking at Protractor's webpage on debugging:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md

The section on testing Protractor interactively seems to indicate that testing interactively is simple as running "Protractor --elementExplorer".  However, when doing this, instead of  ">" prompt the command line returns the following:

Starting debugger agent.
Debugger listening on port 5858

I'm never given a prompt after this.  I must be missing something?  Is there a configuration file somewhere with a flag set incorrectly?

Output from protractor --troubleshoot --elementExplorer:

DEBUG - Running with --troubleshoot
DEBUG - Protractor version: 1.7.0
DEBUG - Your base url for tests is (my test website)
DEBUG - Attempting to find the SeleniumServerJar in the default location used by webdriver-manager
DEBUG - Attempting to find the chromedriver binary in the default location used by webdriver-manager
Starting selenium standalone server...
Selenium standalone server started at http://172.23.5.122:51131/wd/hub
DEBUG - WebDriver session successfully started with capabilities { caps_:
   { applicationCacheEnabled: false,
     rotatable: false,
     mobileEmulationEnabled: false,
     chrome: { userDataDir: 'C:\Users\i65414\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7936_4453' },
     takesHeapSnapshot: true,
     databaseEnabled: false,
     handlesAlerts: true,
     version: '40.0.2214.111',
     platform: 'XP',
     browserConnectionEnabled: false,
     nativeEvents: true,
     acceptSslCerts: true,
     'webdriver.remote.sessionid': '2988bde6-201b-45cb-9638-8ca5e84da857',
     locationContextEnabled: true,
     webStorageEnabled: true,
     browserName: 'chrome',
     takesScreenshot: true,
     javascriptEnabled: true,
     cssSelectorsEnabled: true } }
Starting debugger agent.
Debugger listening on port 5858

Comment: Can you provide the result of running 'protractor --troubleshoot --elementExplorer'

Comment: I've added the result of that command.  I apologize for the formatting; it looked fine in the preview pane, but now it looks like garbage.  I also had to remove a link in order to post it because I can only post a certain number of links in my submission with how many reputation points I have.

Comment: This looks like the windows issue reported here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1822. Do you have a non windows machine to verify if that is the case?

Comment: I don't have one available to me at the moment.  If this is an issue specific to 1.7.0, is there an easy way to rollback to 1.6.1 as a test?

Comment: npm install -g protractor@1.6.1

Comment: I'm having the same issue using protractor 1.8 on a Macbook Pro. Also, when using `browser.pause()` I cannot press `c` or `repl`: "unrecognized command"

Comment: with protractor 1.4 even, it is reproducible